# python dictionary error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'item'

Tags: python, dictionary

I am getting an unexpected error. I realize that there are posts with similar errors but either could not understand the answer or could not relate it to my case (dictionary).

I am trying to calculate a similarity score for each line of an input file and at every iteration (i.e for each line of input file) store the top 20 values of the score in a dictionary.

Following is my code:

```
result={}
//code for computation of score for each line of an input file

if (len(result)<20):
    result[str(line)]=score
else:
    if(len(result)==20):
        result = sorted(result.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
        if(result.item()[19].value()<score):
            result.item()[19][str(line)]=score
```

The error is:

```
File "retrieve.py", line 45, in <module>
if(result.item()[19].value()<score):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'item'
```

Comment: There is no `item` method of either dictionaries or lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
result = sorted(result.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

`result` is not a dictionary anymore.

If I am not mistaken, your problem can be solved this way (assuming `lines` comes from somewhere):

```
result = sorted({(calculate_score(line), line) for line in lines})
print(result[:20])
```

Take a look at [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes) for making an ordered dictionary.

Comment: How else could i sort the dictionary by value, so that i can perform the operaions i want

Comment: @naka: there is no way to sort a dictionary: dictionaries don't have an order.

Comment: @naka Pass the sorted list `result` to `collections.OrderedDict`.

Comment: @naka what exactly were you trying to do?

Comment: @Elazar : I have an input file, each line of which has a set of words. Next i take a query and compute similarity scores between each line of the input file and the query. I am trying to do this by using dictionary, keeping the maximum size of dictionary as 20(to get top 20 results, if sorted by value)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary : Let me try that out.

Comment: @naka Then I think you don't need a dictionary at all. you need to assign a score to each line in a *list*, then sort it and get lst[:20]. use `set` if you need unique lines.

Comment: @Elazar : If i use a list of scores, how do i retrieve the line corresponding to a score?

Comment: @naka If you want a line corresponding to a score, you will need the reverses mapping (like the one I put in the answer). but for up to the query time, all you need is a list of tuples.